# What is the correct way to read strings or send strings to a qtextbrowser from another class using python and pyqt gui?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

I'm trying to send a string from one class to a qtextbrowser located in another class, my gui is built in pyqt and the code i wrote it in python 2.7.

Here is my test code:

```
class print_text():
    def __init__(self):
        text1 = "Acesta este un text de proba"
        self.classMyWindow = MyWindow()
        self.classMyWindow.statusText_updater("Merge ok ")

class systemValues(QThread):
    def __init__(self):
        QThread.__init__(self)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def cpuRunValue(self):
        text1 = "Acesta este un text de proba"
        self.classMyWindow = MyWindow()
        self.classMyWindow.statusText_updater("Merge ok ")

    def run(self):
        self.cpuRunValue()

class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        #QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()
        file_path = os.path.abspath("im-manager.ui")
        uic.loadUi(file_path, self)
        self.myThread = systemValues()
        self.myThread.start()

   def statusText_updater(self,text):
       time_print = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S")
       read1 = self.status.toPlainText()
       self.status.setText(text+" >>> "+time_print+" \n"+ read1+" ") 

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.show()
    # app.exec_()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I get this error:

```
QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread
```

What is the correct way to read strings or send strings to a qtextbrowser from another class?

I need this because my app needs to read some cpu and ram values on a different thread to keep my app from freezing and display a text message when the job is done.

[UI File](https://pastebin.com/Etpw694q)

Comment: Where have you defined statusText_updater?

Comment: sorry, my mistake. forgot about this def. i updated the code @eyllanesc

Comment: MyWindow is QMainWindow or QDialog?, What template did you use for im-manager.ui?

Comment: QMainWindow, you can see it here `class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow)`

Comment: `QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        super(MyWindow, self).__init__()`?

Comment: Why do you initialize these classes?

Comment: Where do you use the `print_text `class?

Comment: You could share the .ui file

Comment: `QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self) ` these one left from another project of mine, o copied it but i didnt noticed it, thanks for pointing it out. `super(MyWindow, self).__init__()` this one build my gui, without it the gui wont show on screen. `print_text` is not used yet. i can share my .ui file. i'll try with a link or pastebin.

Comment: @eyllanesc updated with a pastebin link, tell me if you can use it or you wish to use other services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show data from a QThread in a window it is not necessary to create an instance, since the one you are creating will be different from the original window.

To display data from the thread to the GUI you must do it through signals and connect it to a slot that updates the data each time the signal is emitted.

In this case we will create the newMessage signal and emit it:

```
newMessage  = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
#emit signal
self.newMessage.emit("Merge ok ")
```

Then we connect it to the statusText_updater slot

```
self.myThread.newMessage.connect(self.statusText_updater)
```

Complete code:

```
class systemValues(QtCore.QThread):
    newMessage  = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def cpuRunValue(self):
        text1 = "Acesta este un text de proba"
        self.newMessage.emit("Merge ok ")


    def run(self):
        self.cpuRunValue()

class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self, parent=parent)
        file_path = os.path.abspath("im-manager.ui")
        uic.loadUi(file_path, self)
        self.myThread = systemValues()
        self.myThread.newMessage.connect(self.statusText_updater)
        self.myThread.start()

    def statusText_updater(self,text):
        time = datetime.datetime.now()
        time_print = time.strftime("%d/%m/%Y-%H:%M:%S")
        read1 = self.status.toPlainText()
        self.status.setText(text+" >>> "+time_print+" \n"+ read1+" ")
```

As this is now your `QThread` class will only display once the message, if you want the message to be shown from time to time you must modify the run method:

```
def run(self):
    while True:
        self.cpuRunValue()
        time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: is this the same when you want to read a value from `class MyWindow` or the procedure is different? i want to be "bi-directional". ??

Comment: Yes, you must create a signal in `class Window` and connect it to a slot that updates a `class systemValues` attribute.

Comment: In pyqt the natural way of sending data is through signals and slots.

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because of your threading, not just because you have multiple classes. Whenever threading, you should always use signals and slots to communicate changes within the GUI thread that you would like to trigger. Check out this link for comprehensive examples:
http://pythoncentral.io/pysidepyqt-tutorial-creating-your-own-signals-and-slots/